# How to build and deploy dockerized PHP application in dockerized Jenkins

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm going to use Jenkins to build and deploy my PHP (Laravel) application. That's why I decided to use this http://jenkins-php.org/ decision to reach my purpose. But I'm a fun of Docker and it's a reason why I dared to create my own Docker images that implemented decision above. Here it is: https://github.com/AntonKozytskyi/jenkins-php.

For my Laravel App I have a decision that looks similar this https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock.

Totally I have both Jenkins and Laravel App working via Docker.

I would like to run Jenkins job that:

- gets Laravel App project from Bitbucket repo (this point have already
  reached by using bitbucket plugin:
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin);
- runs docker-compose.xml to build and start containers;
- launch Ant tasks (composer install, various code checks, phpunit and so on);
- publish project to another server if checks above was passed.

What is the right way to build Laravel App working under Docker in Jenkins that is working under Docker as well?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.